Tailsum Formula and Indicator Functions
In my probability theory class we proved that $$\mathbb{E}[x]=\int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}(X>t) dt,$$ where $X\geq0$ is a non-negative random variable and $\mathbb{E}[X]:= \int_\Omega X(\omega) d\mathbb{P}(\omega)$. We proved it the following way,
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}(X>t) dt &= \int_0^\infty\int_\Omega \textbf{1}_{X>t}(\omega) \ d\mathbb{P}(\omega) \ dt \\ &= \int_\Omega \int_0^\infty \textbf{1}_{X>t}(\omega) \  dt \ d\mathbb{P}(\omega) \\ &= \int_\Omega \int_0^{X(\omega)} dt \ d\mathbb{P}(\omega) \\ &=\int_\Omega X(\omega) d\mathbb{P}(\omega).
\end{align}
I don't understand how he gets from the second equality to the third (not Fubini) i.e. why is
$$\int_0^\infty \textbf{1}_{X>t}(\omega) \  dt = \int_0^{X(\omega)} dt.$$
In general, in this class my professor keeps throwing up indicator functions everywhere and casually "manipulates" them, which I have a hard time following. If you've taken this class and understand what I'm trying to say, can you also please tell me how you think about indicator functions intuitively?

I think what you might be missing here, is that the indicator refers to $t$ in the integral, not $X$.
In case you have trouble understanding the limits, draw a $t$-axis, throw a random point $X$ on it, and find the indicator that (note the notation!) $t \le X$. That would be one everywhere where $t$ is indeed less than the thrown $X$ and zero otherwise.

I think this painting could be helpful. You can play around with $a$.
